# unzip in root directory while preserving file structure

Tags: linux, zip

I want to unzip the entire content of a zip file to the root of my server.

However each time i try to do this it creates a folder name for the file.

The zip file is called src.zip

the file is at the root of my site.

i used the following command

```
unzip src.zip
```

This unzips it but then create a folder called src and places the content there.

I want all of the content to be in the root of site and not in the folder.

Comment: The unzip command has parameters that will put the target extract where you want:  https://learn.akamai.com/en-us/webhelp/netstorage/netstorage-user-guide/GUID-80C7B749-F9BB-4271-A138-AEEED1070D11.html

Answer (score 0):

Zip files don't store absolute paths. Below is from the zip spec, [APPNOTE.TXT](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT)

```
   4.4.17.1 The name of the file, with optional relative path.
   The path stored MUST NOT contain a drive or
   device letter, or a leading slash.  All slashes
   MUST be forward slashes '/' as opposed to
   backwards slashes '\' for compatibility with Amiga
   and UNIX file systems etc.  If input came from standard
   input, there is no file name field.
```

To get the zipfile to extract to a specific location, use the `-d` option. This will extract the contents of the zip to the directory specified.

Like so

```
unzip -d / src.zip
```